# When does Outlook's Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse property return null?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm attempting to determine when Outlook's Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse property will return null. The [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) states, *"This property returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic) if no inline response is visible in the Reading Pane"*.

So far I've only been able to get ActiveInlineResponse to return null when sending mail from outside of Outlook. For example, a Word/Excel mail merge or from a VBA project that uses Outlook to send mail. Are there any other instances where ActiveInlineResponse will return null?
I'm only concerned with Outlook mailitems.

Here's my question in code-

```
        Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

        if (explorer.ActiveInlineResponse is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            if (explorer.ActiveInlineResponse == null)
            {
                //When would the ActiveInlineResponse be null?
            }

            else if (explorer.ActiveInlineResponse != null)
            {
                //ActiveInlineResponse is not null when an item is being composed inline (reply,reply all or forward)
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to use the `ActiveInlineResponse` property? What is your goal?

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for your response. Basically my goal is to identify mailitems being sent through Outlook that are not Outlook generated(ie - VBA, PowerShell, mail merge). I need to check the body for test before sending. I thought there might be a way to identify a mail item property that would distinguish this but can't seem to locate anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course - this is to be expected: Word/Excel etc. do not use inline response to send messages, they show messages in a separate inspector, which can be retrieved using `Application.ActiveInspector`.

Inline response (`Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse`) is only shown when a user replies to or forwards a message.

Comment: Perfect Thanks! Just wanted to make sure there was not another way it might be null that I hadn't  considered.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no call the `ActiveExplorer` method twice in the code:

```
Outlook.Explorer explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
explorer = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
```

To get the currently selected item in Outlook's explorer windows you can use the [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.selection) property of the `Explorer` class which returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window. For example:

```
private void DisplaySelectedItems()
{
    Outlook.Selection selection =
        Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
    for (int i = 1; i <= selection.Count; i++)
    {
        OutlookItem myItem = new OutlookItem(selection[i]);
        myItem.Display();
    }
}
```

The [Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property returns an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane (as it states, it is available for for any responses like replies and forwards).

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)

Comment: ah, yes thanks! I was trying to explain my question a little better though code. Not necessarily provide working code.