# Sort email in the reading pane into subfolder according to key word in the subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to sort emails from the inbox into subfolders according to key words in the subject.

Specifically, I want the email in the reading pane to go into the applicable subfolder after using the shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.
This should also trigger a message box with the options to click on "OK" or "Cancel".
"Cancel" removes the email from the subfolder and puts it into the inbox again.

The shortcut doesn't work and the SubjectFilter code gives an error message

> an object couldn't be found

```vb
Sub CreateFilterShortcut()
    Application.OnKey "^%q", "SubjectFilter"
End Sub

Sub SubjectFilter()

    Dim iClick As Integer
     Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
     Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
     Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
     Dim olMsg As Outlook.Items
 
     Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
     Set olApp = Outlook.Application
     Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
     Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
     Set olMsg = olFolder.Items
     Set myDestFolder1 = objNS.Folders("Folder1")
     Set myDestFolder2 = objNS.Folders("Folder2")

    If myOlExp.olMsg.IsPaneVisible(olPreview) = True Then
        If olMsg.Subject Like "*report1*" Then
            olMsg.Move myDestFolder1
            iClick = MsgBox(prompt:="Folder1", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)
          
        ElseIf olMsg.Subject Like "*report2*" Then
            olMsg.Move myDestFolder2
            iClick = MsgBox(prompt:="Folder2", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)
        End If
    End If
    
    If iClick = vbCancel Then
        MsgBox "Cancel"
        olMsg.Move olFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "Ok"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Sorry, Set myDestFolder1 = objNS.Folders("Folder1")

Comment: If you cannot find previously answered questions, you can post separate questions about assigning code to a shortcut and determining the item being displayed in the preview pane.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `Folder1` a level too high. You could try

```
Set myDestFolder1 = objNS.Folders("your.email@wherever.com").Folders("Folder1")
```

Edit: I used the Watch window to determine what folders were available under objNS if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

There are two items in your code which need to be surveyed.

- olMsg is an inbuilt constant. Replaced with `olMessages`
- The assignment is resulted in a collection, which has to be iterated through. Does with a `For...Each loop`
- The user folders has to be under one of your e-mail folders

```
Sub SubjectFilter()

 Dim iClick As Integer
 Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
 Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Dim inMsg As Outlook.Items
 
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
 Set olApp = Outlook.Application
 Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set olMessages = olFolder.Items          'edited
 Set myDestFolder1 = objNS.Folders("youremail@mailserver.ext").Folders("Folder1")  'edited
 Set myDestFolder2 = objNS.Folders("youremail@mailserver.ext").Folders("Folder2")  'edited


    'If myOlExp.olMsg.IsPaneVisible(olPreview) = True Then
    For each inMsg in olMessages        'inserted
    If inMsg.Subject Like "*report1*" Then   'edited
      inMsg.Move myDestFolder1               'edited
      iClick = MsgBox(prompt:="Folder1", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)
          
    ElseIf inMsg.Subject Like "*report2*" Then   'edited
      inMsg.Move myDestFolder2                   'edited 
      iClick = MsgBox(prompt:="Folder2", Buttons:=vbOKCancel)
    End If
    'End If
    next inMsg                'inserted

    If iClick = vbCancel Then
    MsgBox "Cancel"
    inMsg.Move olFolder          'edited
    Else
    MsgBox "Ok"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

In Outlook there is no OnKey method.

Cannot declare user-defined custom shortcuts or reassign them. There are workarounds of it e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/203294/custom-one-key-keyboard-shortcuts-in-outlook-2010-or-2013 , which uses the AutoHotKey.

Comment: However you can create Folder in the root too with from .pst extension Outlook Data File, if not necessary use only folders within your account.

Comment: `Dim inMsg As Object`

Comment: You cannot reverse a move this way. You have to keep a reference to `inMsg`. Simpler to do the test earlier `If MsgBox(prompt:="Folder1", Buttons:=vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then inMsg.Move myDestFolder1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes the destination folders are subfolders of the default inbox.

```vb
Sub SubjectFilter()

    Dim olFolder As Folder
    Dim myDestFolder1 As Folder
    Dim myDestFolder2 As Folder
    
    Set olFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myDestFolder1 = olFolder.Folders("Folder1")
    Set myDestFolder2 = olFolder.Folders("Folder2")
 
    Dim myOlExp As explorer
    Set myOlExp = ActiveExplorer
    
    Dim olMsg As Object
    
    If myOlExp.IsPaneVisible(olPreview) = True Then
    
        ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse
        
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/71241179/1571407
        ' ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse is only shown when a user replies to or forwards a message.
        'Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
        
        'If olMsg Is Nothing Then
        Set olMsg = ActiveExplorer.selection(1)
        'End If
        
        Debug.Print olMsg.Subject
        
        If olMsg.Subject Like "*report1*" Then
            If MsgBox(prompt:="Folder1", Buttons:=vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
                olMsg.Move myDestFolder1
            End If
            
        ElseIf olMsg.Subject Like "*report2*" Then
            If MsgBox(prompt:="Folder2", Buttons:=vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
                olMsg.Move myDestFolder2
            End If
            
        End If
    
    End If
    
End Sub
```

A move reversal requires a reference to the moved item, not the original item. Better to verify before moving not after.